# How to simultaneously create a new folder and multiple files in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I discovered recently in Visual Studio Code that I can create a new folder and a new file simultaneously by using the following patten: Test/Test.jsx

eg.

1: Right click and select 'New File'.
[image: New File]

2: Enter desired folder and file name.
[image: Enter folder and file name]

3: The result from step 1 & 2.
[image: Folder and file creation]

Anyone know if it's possible to create a folder with multiple files using a similar pattern? This is what I'd like to be able to do.
[image: Add multiple files to a new folder]

Comment: Also see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980558/recording-a-macro-or-a-serios-of-actions-in-visual-studio-code/64289429#64289429 which creates a folder and number of files with default content in each for a different approach. Your situation was simpler since you didn't require any content added to each file.

Comment: I still was thinking they would use the same glob format as webpack.

```Test/Test.{component,styles}.jsx```

Comment: I think it would be nice if we could do something like `MyNewFolder/index.tsx,styles.ts` using the comma to declare the two new files under the new folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can do it the way you showed, but it is pretty easy to do it with a task.  In your tasks.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",

  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "new react folder and files",

      "command": "mkdir ${input:dirName} && touch '${input:dirName}/${input:dirName}.component.jsx' '${input:dirName}/${input:dirName}.styles.jsx'",

      "type": "shell",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "presentation": {
        "echo": false,
        "reveal": "silent",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": false,
        "clear": true
      },
   }
],  

// ........................................................................................
  
  "inputs": [

    {
      "type": "promptString",
      "id": "dirName",
      "description": "Complete my folder name",
      "default": "jsx folder to create"
    }
  ]
}
```

And some keybinding to trigger the task (in your keybindings.json):

```
[
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "new react folder and files",
  }
]
```

This will prompt for the directory name and then create the folder and two files within it.

[I used bash commands `mkdir` and `touch` to create the folder and files, if you are using a shell without those commands swap out the ones you have.]

[image: create a react folder and files with a task]

Comment: Thanks Mark! This looks like it would do the trick. More initial setup then I wanted, but it will be worth it. Can you direct me how to get to my tasks.JSON and keybindings.JSON?

Comment: Under the `.vscode` folder just create a `tasks.json` file and you can paste in what I showed.  For the `keybindings.json`, look for `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the command palette.

Comment: I've found this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liuyang.quick-create . If necessary, you can use Google Translate to understand the instructions ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. I think faster would be to use **Intergrated Terminal** option

[image]

2. After select Git Bash (any bash interpreter)

[image]

and paste command with i.e "test" as directory and after / files you want to create (u get the idea ). If you want to create only files u can use "touch" instead of "mkdir -p"

```
mkdir -p test/validateAdAccounts.ts \
test/validateAccountsInPask.ts \
test/validateUsers.ts \
test/validateGroups.ts \
test/validateMainMappingAttributes.ts
```

and enter

Comment: not working in mac. it create a .ts file as a folder.

Comment: Can you tell what terminal are you using to run wchich command?

Comment: i tried the original terminal in mac , also iterm with bash or zsh. neither works.

at then end I used

mkdir -p folder1/folder2/folder3 && touch folder1/folder2/folder3/index.ts