# vscode - how to store series of steps and play later

Tags: visual-studio-code, automation

I have used notepad++ and I used to store series of steps as macros and play them later whenever I need. Is there a way that I can do the same in vscode?

I have tried a few extensions that are available on marketplace, but they did not work.

Comment: if you want to name them use `multi-command` if you want to bind them only to a key combo use the `runComamnds` command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recording a 'macro'? or a series of actions in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980558/recording-a-macro-or-a-series-of-actions-in-visual-studio-code)